# Amenable Groups and Short Exact Sequences

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, category-theory

Let $1 \to K \to \Gamma \to H \to 1$ be an exact sequence of groups. Show that $\Gamma$ is an amenable group if and only if $K, H$ are amenable.

---

I have already shown the first direction, by writing $H = \Gamma/K$ and playing with fundamental domains. However, I'm lost when I'm trying to prove the second direction (again, I think the fact that $H=\Gamma/K$ may be useful here). I have seen some proofs using invariant means, however I wanted to prove the statement in a more group theoretic way. The definition of amenability I have is that $\Gamma$ (countable) is amenable if there exists a finitely additive probability measure $\mu: 2^{\Gamma} \to [0,1]$ such that it is invariant under left translation.

What would be a way to get started with this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $\Gamma \ne H/K$, you probably mean that $H\cong \Gamma/K$. Do you have hard time proving that subgroups of amenable groups are amenable? Or the quotients?

Comment: Let $f\colon K\to \Gamma, g\colon \Gamma \to H$. Isn't that the case that the measures induced on $K$ and $H$ by the amenability of $\Gamma$ turn $H,K$ into amenable? There is a measure $f_!\mu$ on $K$ defined by $2^K\xrightarrow{f_!} 2^\Gamma \xrightarrow{\mu}[0,1]$, where $f_!(U) = \bigcup\{ V\mid fU\subseteq V\}$ and there is a measure $g^*\mu$ on $H$ defined by $2^H\xrightarrow{g^*} 2^\Gamma \xrightarrow{\mu}[0,1]$ where $g^*(V) = g^\leftarrow V$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $H \simeq \Gamma/K$ as you described. @FoscoLoregian that's kind of what I did for the problem, however I'm having trouble showing that if both $K, H$ are amenable, then $\Gamma$ is as well. Maybe I'm missing something simple.